# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "#<RecipeType:0x000055cd000b18a0>":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've been having trouble to do a challenge with Active Records, I read the documentation, and seen other examples with `belongs_to` that I remade and worked, I have no clue anymore about what I'm doing wrong here when I try to call recipe.recipe_type.name I get the error Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "#":String

schema.rb

```
  create_table "recipe_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "recipe_type_id"
    t.index ["recipe_type_id"], name: "index_recipe_types_on_recipe_type_id"
  end

  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "cuisine"
    t.string "difficulty"
    t.integer "cook_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "ingredients"
    t.text "cook_method"
  end
end
```

migrations

```
  def change
    create_table :recipes do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :cuisine
      t.string :difficulty
      t.integer :cook_time

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class AddFieldsToRecipe < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :recipes, :ingredients, :text
    add_column :recipes, :cook_method, :text
  end
end
```

```
class CreateRecipeTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :recipe_types do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class AddRecipeRefToRecipeType < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :recipe_types, :recipe_type, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemed to have added the `recipe_type` reference to the wrong table. Your last migration should probably have been

```
add_reference :recipes, :recipe_type, foreign_key: true
```

because as it is, you have added the reference_type reference to ReferenceType.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that, did a rollback and changed it, but now I'm getting  `NameError (undefined local variable or method `recipe_type'`

Comment: Have you specified `belongs_to :recipe_type` in your Recipe model?

Comment: Okay, maybe you are trying to call recipe_type somewhere, when you should really be calling recipe. Search for recipe_type and try to find the incorrect usage. If you still can get it to work, edit your question and include the full error callback log

Answer (score 0):

So the final schema was:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_03_26_013134) do

  create_table "recipe_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["recipe_id"], name: "index_recipe_types_on_recipe_id"
  end

  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "cuisine"
    t.string "difficulty"
    t.integer "cook_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "ingredients"
    t.text "cook_method"
    t.integer "recipe_type_id"
    t.index ["recipe_type_id"], name: "index_recipes_on_recipe_type_id"
  end
end
```

and with

models/recipe_type

```
class RecipeType < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipes
end
```

models/recipe

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe_type
end
```

You can start a simple has_many belongs_to active record association, I hope this helps as many people as those who helped me, in the beginning of this journey, strongly recommend to study db:migrate, db:rollback, db:create and db:drop for those who encounter some trouble.